# Using JSON and http request to get data in android. Get request doesnt work

Tags: php, android, json, http, httprequest

I am trying to get the JSON result from my php code in my android app.
It works well if I need all database entries like:

```
public class GetAllFromOnlineDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    private static final String TAG = "GET_ALL";

    // URL to get all stolpersteine
    private static final String URL_ALL_STOLPERSTEINE = "http://.../get_all.php";


    // JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_STOLPERSTEINE = "stolpersteine";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
    private static final String TAG_LAST_NAME = "last_name";

    // Creating JSON parser object
    private JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    private MapControl mapControl;

    public GetAllFromOnlineDatabase(MapControl mapControl) {
        this.mapControl = mapControl;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        // Building parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // Getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALL_STOLPERSTEINE, "GET", params);

        try {
            // Checking for success TAG in JSON
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                // Getting array of products
                JSONArray memory_list_stolpersteine_table_row = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STOLPERSTEINE);

                // looping through all products
                for (int i = 0; i < memory_list_stolpersteine_table_row.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = memory_list_stolpersteine_table_row.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = jsonObject.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String title = jsonObject.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String first_name = jsonObject.getString(TAG_FIRST_NAME);
                    String last_name = jsonObject.getString(TAG_LAST_NAME);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error - cannot read JSON");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        cancel(true);
    }

}
```

but if I used another URL to get details with GET request like below it doesnt work. The json object in android is empty. How can I fix this? Thanks

```
private static final String URL_ALL_STOLPERSTEINE = "http://.../get_geopoint_by_id.php?pid=1";
```

Comment: Does the GET-Request even work? It probably returns a different result than get_all.php

Comment: It works with the browser and it returns the correct data, but not in the app. It looks like there is a problem with ?pid=1 in the JSONObject.

Comment: Before trying to parse the JSON you should make sure the request is working correctly!

Comment: If I open the url in my browser and it shows me the correct data the request is working correctly?

Comment: Is it your API? If not there could be a Browser-Check, Crossorigin-Check or anything similar